# What is the best approach to design model fields that is like a list in Django?

Tags: python, django, list, model

Let's say I have a model called '`SysApp`'. Each system has 5 documents. Each document has fields:

- Title
- URL to the file (external url)
- Description

Rather than defining multiple fields like

- title_1,
- url_1,
- description_1,
- title_2,
- url_2,
- description_2
  (Hardcoded approach)

is there a better way to handle this type of use case?

One way of doing is to create a model storing each document and then SysApp will reference each document using a `ForeignKey`. However I still have to create field like `document_1, document_2` etc. Also it would be quite difficult for editors to manage when there are **100+ SysApp and 3-400+ documents**.

Is it possible to manage these fields like a list or dictionary?

Thank you

Comment: Your second approach is correct, but instead of a ForeignKey (1 to many) you should investigate ManyToMany relations and `FormSet`s.

Comment: Thank you @Kjjassy. One thing I might not have said clearly. The documents are unlikely to be shared. eg 'installation document' it's only for 1 SysApp. In this case while using a ForeignKey(or M2M) can simplify some of the code, but end up I have a repository of 'document' item which most of them are obsoleted (no editor delete the linked document before adding a new one :(

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to organize your 'SysApp - documents' relationship, assuming that each document is related to only one sysapp, is to use `ForeignKey`, as you mentioned.

In that case you'll only have to create 2 models: the first one is `SysApp` with a `name` field and the second is `Document` with fields `title`, `url to file`, `description` and a `foreignkey` to `SysApp`. Now you can create documents and attach them to the sys you want. So you do not need to specify `document_2`, `document_3` etc. fields.

If you need to attach one document to more than one sysapp use `ManyToMany` instead of `ForeignKey`.

Comment: Thank you @chem1st. I have put my comment above.